# Angularjs Filter comparison with two numbers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a collection of fields and a collection of pages.  Each field has a `pageNumber` property and each page has a `pageNumber` property.  In my filter, I want to only list the fields that match the page that I'm currently on in the parent ng-repeat.  This works great unless I have 10 pages in the pages collection because then it lists all the fields in any pages 10 through 19 on page one also.  I assume that somehow the filter I'm using returns a positive match when 1=1, 1=10, 1=11, 1=12, etc. for some reason.  How can I make sure the comparison it matches the pages correctly?

```
<div ng-repeat="p in model.pages">
    <div ng-repeat="f in model.fields | filter: { pageNumber: p.pageNumber }">
        <div class="pdf-field">{{f.pageNumber}} = {{p.pageNumber}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `:true` at the end. It matches for strict equality only:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in model.fields | filter: { pageNumber: p.pageNumber }:true">
```